# Testing Secrets in NetSuite SuiteScript for API Keys

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to write an API connector for NetSuite to connect to a third-party service, and want to store the API key in a Secret. I have seen several QA's regard this, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75214515/how-can-i-successfully-integrate-a-service-with-netsuite-using-a-restlet-instead), but what I can't figure out is how to know if the the Secret was successfully fetched.

The service I need to connect to is antiquated, and requires the API key sent as a POST parameter, and I want to check that my script is correctly loading the key from the Secret, but every time I try to `log.debug()` it, nothing comes out. Below are two examples I've tried, one with `https`, and the other with `crypto`. The Secret does exist in my account at the ID `custsecret_demo_key`, and is set to be accessible to all scripts (I'll narrow the scope once I get it working at all). Each of these thoroughly referenced Oracle's own examples on accessing Secrets.

It is possible to print the value of the Secret to the log to ensure it's working? If not, how am I supposed to know if it does or doesn't?

**https**

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/log', 'N/https'],
    
    function(log, https) {
        const beforeLoad = (scriptContext) => {
            const apiKey = https.createSecureString({input: '{custsecret_demo_key}'});

            log.debug({
                title: "connector test",
                details: apiKey,
            });
        };

        return {
            beforeLoad: beforeLoad
        };
});
```

Logs: `{}`

**crypto**

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/log', 'N/crypto', 'N/encode'],
    
    function(log, crypto, encode) {
        const beforeLoad = (scriptContext) => {
            const apiKey = crypto.createSecretKey({secret: '{custsecret_demo_key}', encoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8});

            log.debug({
                title: "connector test",
                details: apiKey,
            });
        };

        return {
            beforeLoad: beforeLoad
        };
});
```

Logs: `{"secret":"{custsecret_dt_api_key}","encoding":"UTF_8"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently using NS secrets in my integrations as it is the most secure way to handle keys. However, it can be kind of tricky as you will never be able to log the secret (which makes sense).
Test it out by trying to hit the api and look at the response. Try something like this to get the url:

```
  let baseReqUrl = https.createSecureString({
    input: 'www.myapi.com/?keyparameter='
});
let key = https.createSecureString({
    input: `{custsecret_api_secret}`
});
let completeUrl = baseReqUrl.appendSecureString({
    secureString: key
});
```

Comment: I need to pass the Secret as a parameter of the POST body, e.g. `api_key=<my key>`. Does this method allow for that?

Comment: It does. You will need to add the key to the rest of your post body and pass it as the input for the createSecureString method

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include an example of that? I tried it myself a couple of different ways just now, and keeping getting a response from the API indicating that no key was sent. I have double and triple checked that the key exists at the ID I'm passing it.

Comment: I was checking the link to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75214515/how-can-i-successfully-integrate-a-service-with-netsuite-using-a-restlet-instead) for this integration and in the first response there is a really good example for it in the format you're needing. 

I currently have a working script with a basic auth header that uses secrets and it goes like this:
let ordersResponse = https.get({url: reqUrl, headers: { 'Authorization': authHeader } });
where authHeader is:

Comment: let basicString = https.createSecureString({input: 'Basic '});
let completeString = https.createSecureString({input: `{${connectionData.clientKey}}:{${connectionData.clientSecret}}`});
let encodedString = completeString.convertEncoding({fromEncoding: https.Encoding.UTF_8,toEncoding: https.Encoding.BASE_64});
let authHeader = basicString.appendSecureString({secureString: encodedString,keepEncoding: true});

Comment: Thank you! Now it worked, and since your answer confirms that you cannot log the output of retrieved secrets, I've accepted this as the answer.

Comment: @CaroGorriaran would the connectionData.clientKey and connectionData.clientSecret in this case be references to API Secret IDs or just the key and secret stored in variables in your code?

Comment: @nyy I just keep my secret ids stored in a custom record - if this were hardcoded, it would look like this: completeString = https.createSecureString({input: {custsecret_whateveridforkey}:{custsecret_whateveridforsecret}});

Comment: @CaroGorriaran I appreciate the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I found the same issue while integrating Netsuite with another system. Then, I kept the credentials in a JSON file in the FileCabinet and I used them from there. I just protected such a file to be accessible only by the script and by the Netsuite Admin to warrant the ApiKey security. The code below can help you to find yours...

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/log', 'N/file'],
    
    function(log, file) {
        const beforeLoad = (scriptContext) => {
            
            let cfgFile = file.load(
                {
                    id: cfgFileId
                }).getContents();
            let cfg = JSON.parse(cfgFile);

            const apiKey = cfg.custsecret_demo_key;

            log.debug({
                title: "connector test",
                details: apiKey,
            });
        };

        return {
            beforeLoad: beforeLoad
        };
});
```

You can set the `cfgFileId` either fixed or dynamically. It would be the ID of the file where you are keeping the credentials in the File Cabinet. The JSON file would look like this:

```json
{
    "custsecret_demo_key": "Your key"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll test this out, and see if it fits our needs

Comment: While this does functionally meet my needs, I'm not sure if this actually answers the question. This is just a work around for the actual problem, but I would like to leave the question open for now in hopes that there is a real answer out there.